# jQuery append() doesn't work in IE but works in Chrome

Tags: jquery, flash

In short,
my website has a complex flash and the html is like this

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/open-flash-chart.swf"
width="650" height="300" id="flash_content_aA1Fc6mD" style="visibility: visible; ">
    <param name="flashvars" value="data-file=%2Fother%2Ffinances%2Fgraph.json%3Fgraph%3Dbar%26action%3Dcompare_all%26controller%3Dother%252Ffinances">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
```

In order to let this flash transparent,so i use jquery to append some code ,the jquery code like this

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("object").append("<param name='wmode' value='transparent' />") 
})
```

It so perfect in chrome . but when i open IE6(sadly,more than 20% people use this browser here T_T),i found it doesn't work .

then i debug this code. At first, i guess the problem is `$("object")` ,but then i found ie can run well in ie6.

At last , i found that the reason cause this problem is append(). when i found that i cant append any things to `<object>` in ie6 .

My problem is how to append nodes to `<object>` node in ie6

So Is AnyBody Can Help Me???  HELP !! Or i must work overtime overtime.....

Comment: Friends don't let friends use IE6. http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: Which version of Jquery do you work? As far as I can remember the author of jquery had made a cut with supporting IE6

Comment: legacy versions of jQuery are available at http://code.jquery.com/index.html (jQuery 1.2.6 for example ought to work even with IE6)

Comment: I use jquery 1.7.1 and 1.6.4 . You means i should use earlier versions?

Comment: [This page](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility) states that in fact IE6 is supported. Btw why do you append that code with jQuery, when it seems to already exist in the HTML you showed?

Comment: you're right, it's only jQuery 2.0 that will drop IE6: http://blog.jquery.com/2012/07/01/jquery-1-9-and-2-0-tldr-edition/

Comment: so back to original question, SeasonHuang, have you tried creating a very simple page that has only the `<object>` tag in the body? if you do, does the append() work in IE6? if so, it's probably not jQuery but something else that's causing the problem

Comment: I want add that code in `<object>`, it doesn't has that code when the second part jquery code run.
I make a simple page to test this problem . and i consider that i really can't append any node to  `<object>` node in ie6

Comment: [Here is the corresponding bug ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11280) in the jQuery bug tracker. Seems like it's an IE6-8 problem, and the bug is still open. It suggests that the problem is with `appendChild` itself, not jQuery.

Comment: Very Thanks bažmegakapa . I will ues pure javascript to slove this.
thank you